# how to take the url from the url and compare it to a given table in php

Tags: php, database, mysqli

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    <?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>
</button>

<?php 
    $goturl=$_GET['url'];

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","stud_user","123456","stud_db");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Oops! We ran into some problem!" . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE url='<?=$goturl;?>'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['verification_value'];
    }

    if($verification_value == 'UNVERIFIED'){ 
        $val = 'UNVERIFIED';
    } else { 
        $val = 'VERIFIED';
    }
?>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info"> <?php echo $val; ?> </button>
<br />  
<?php mysqli_close($con); ?>
<hr />
```

Hi i am a newbie in php and i m currently using this code to fetch the site.php?url=website.com and then use the fetched url to check a given db but seems i m not able to make it work i m missing something that i cannot understand. also this always show that the url is verified. what am i doing wrong here? Please help me thank a lot for your help! :)

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE url=$goturl"); You have nested <?php tags.

Comment: You need ajax. You can't call php code after page has loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$goturl = $_GET['url'];
$goturl = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $goturl); 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE url='$goturl' LIMIT 1");
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['verification_value'];
}
else
{
    echo "No in Table";
}
```

Comment: both the solutions worked great! thanks paula and satish so much :)

Answer (score -1):

You are opening PHP tag within PHP which is invalid, simply do:

```
result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE url='$goturl'");
```

Also it would be a good idea to check whether the GET variable is passed using [isset()](https://www.php.net/isset) before trying in query.

Comment: I can vaguely guess why the down-vote would have landed and to that person: you fail to understand what's more important -> the actual solution or extra security. The correct way would be to leave me a comment asking me to add 'it'.